# Grab contents in lines, and fix the output format

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to use a simple script on centos to take out the information from lines in a file and output to a csv file. currently i had used my script to achieved the result, but cost too much time with it's progress. In my source_file I have 10 million lines with it, and take around 1.5 hours.
Source_File:

```
Jun 0:0:1.83 Q: I: C 12.25.89.22#408: V xx: Q: aa.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.83 Q: I: C 14.25.87.12#302: V dd: Q: bb.try.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.83 Q: I: C 19.46.41.13#361: V bb: Q: cc.try.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.98 Q: I: C 14.25.89.16#435: V ss: Q: dd.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.98 Q: I: C 14.25.86.28#353: V gg: Q: cc.ee.try.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 14.25.89.23#423: V xx: Q: .test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 13.21.85.12#356: V dd: Q: gg-1-2.try.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 19.46.40.32#451: V dd: Q: hh.try.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 24.78.62.18#139: V ss: Q: .try.com IN(B)
```

Data_File :

```
test.com/
try.com/
try.test.com/
```

Result :

```
12.25.89.22,xx,test.com
14.25.87.12,dd,try.com
19.46.41.13,bb,try.test.com
14.25.89.16,ss,test.com
14.25.86.28,gg,try.test.com
14.25.89.23,xx,test.com
13.21.85.12,dd,try.com
19.46.40.32,dd,try.com
24.78.62.18,ss,try.com
```

As i tried was took out IP, two words and domain. the domain should be match from Data_File. which the extra string in domain will cut off.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -n '2,$p' Source_File | awk -F '[ #:]' '{print $10 " " $14 " " $18 "/"}' >> Temp_File

awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$0];next} {for (i in arr) {c=match($3,i);n=c&&(!b[$3]||c<b[$3])?i:n;b[$3]=c}$3=n}1' Data_File Temp_File >> Result

sed -i 's/ /,/g;s/\///g' Result

exit
```

It could be cost too much time on matching part, but as a new in linux, only has limited knowledge.
could some talent people give a hint? or could be other simple scripts achieve it? (can be any commands).

Comment: Edited my answer to adjust the domain names

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer, out of interest how long did it take to run for that large file?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it take 13 mins for 13,000,000 lines of file :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Perl`:

```
#! /bin/bash

input=/tmp/file
data=/tmp/data

export regex=$(perl -pe 'chomp; s/\///g; s/$/|/g' $data |\
       perl -pe 's/^/(/g; s/\|$/)/g')

perl -F':|\s|#' -alne '{ 
    $F[17] =~ s/.*?$ENV{"regex"}.*/$1/g; 
    print $F[9].",".$F[13].",".$F[17] }' $input
```

Output:

```
bash test.sh 
12.25.89.22,xx,test.com
14.25.87.12,dd,try.com
19.46.41.13,bb,try.test.com
14.25.89.16,ss,test.com
14.25.86.28,gg,try.test.com
14.25.89.23,xx,test.com
13.21.85.12,dd,try.com
19.46.40.32,dd,try.com
24.78.62.18,ss,try.com
```

Explanation:

1. Create a regex based on `data` file
2. Replace the domains based on that regex
3. Print selected fields

.

Comment: You really using `/tmp/data` to hardcode the domain replacement??? (Took me some time to get it, unbelivable!) You just needed to remove the leftmost portion!

Comment: @hek2mgl I am creating a regex which look like `(test.com|try.com|try.test.com)` there is nothing hard coded, this regex is created based on `Data_file` OP provided.

Comment: No worries, for what's worth I learn a lot with your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution needs too much different processes which are processing the *whole* file again and again. Just a single awk command will do:

*script.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=","
}
NR>1{
    # Remove #...: from the IP
    match($6, /^(.*)#/,m)
    $6=m[1]

    # Get the two letter value
    gsub(":", "", $8)

    # Remove the optional leading dot from domain
    match($10,/\.?(.*)/,m)
    $10=m[1]

    print $6,$8,$10
}
```

Execute:

```
awk -f script.awk input.file
```

I've tested it with 1.2 GB large file containing 18 millions of lines, and it took on my 4 year old desktop: 4 minutes, 33 seconds:

```
$ du -h input.file
1,2G    input.file

$ wc -l input.file
18874368  input.file

$ time awk -f script.awk input.file > output.file

real    4m33.991s
user    4m32.673s
sys 0m1.328s
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, learn alots from it. but I would like to cut off extra string in domain, and domain name is come from Data_File. could be add in same script?

Comment: Yeah, of course you can extend the script. `awk` is quite powerful, you can do everything you need to do with text files.

Comment: It doesn't remove `bb.` from `bb.try.com` I deleted my answer in perl for that reason. It proved to be a bit tricky because OP wants `try.test.com` which has 3 levels as well

Comment: @Tiago I see. Missed that requirement. Need to be AFK for a while, can fix it later. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

Given the following test set:

```
$ cat dns.log 
Jun 0:0:1.83 Q: I: C 12.25.89.22#408: V xx: Q: aa.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.83 Q: I: C 14.25.87.12#302: V dd: Q: bb.try.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.83 Q: I: C 19.46.41.13#361: V bb: Q: cc.try.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.98 Q: I: C 14.25.89.16#435: V ss: Q: dd.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.98 Q: I: C 14.25.86.28#353: V gg: Q: cc.ee.try.test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 14.25.89.23#423: V xx: Q: .test.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 13.21.85.12#356: V dd: Q: gg-1-2.try.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 19.46.40.32#451: V dd: Q: hh.try.com IN(B)
Jun 0:0:1.91 Q: I: C 24.78.62.18#139: V ss: Q: .try.com IN(B)
```

I obtain something that *seems* to be adequate using a single Perl regex substitution:

```
sh$ perl -pe 's/.*C (.*)#.*V (..).*?([^.]*\.[^.]*) IN.*/\1,\2,\3/' < dns.log
12.25.89.22,xx,test.com
14.25.87.12,dd,try.com
19.46.41.13,bb,test.com
14.25.89.16,ss,test.com
14.25.86.28,gg,test.com
14.25.89.23,xx,test.com
13.21.85.12,dd,try.com
19.46.40.32,dd,try.com
24.78.62.18,ss,try.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, learn alots. but the "try.test.com" will also cut off.